# Where does the derivative exists?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Given the function $$f(z)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2y}-i|x+y|$$
I need to find where this function is differentiable( where $f'(z)$ exists).

**What I did:**

$u(x,y)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2y}$,
$v(x,y)=-|x+y|$

First noted that $u(x,y)$ is not real differentiable at $y=0$ and $v(x,y)=-|x+y|$ is not differentiable when $y=-x$. Then, I can say that $f(z)$ is real-differentiable at $D=C-\{x+iy:y=0,y=-x\}$.

Finding the partial derivatives in $D$:
$u_x=-\frac{x}{y}$,$u_y=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)$,$v_x=v_y=-\frac{x+y}{|x+y|}$.

Ok, here's the problem: I'm very confuse because of the absolute value there. I separate into cases for solving the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$x+y\geq 0\Rightarrow$ $$u_x=-\frac{x}{y}=-1=v_y$$ $$u_y=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)=1=-v_x$$
With solution $x=y \wedge x^2=y^2\Rightarrow x=y\wedge y=|x|\Rightarrow x=|x|\Rightarrow x\geq 0$

$x+y<0\Rightarrow$ $$u_x=-\frac{x}{y}=1=v_y$$ $$u_y=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)=-1=-v_x$$
With solution $y=-x\wedge x^2=-3y^2\Rightarrow x=0$.

So, I think the domain where the derivative exists is the intersection of the solutions plus the separation into cases. I found the solution $E=C-\{x+iy:x>0,y>-x\}$. **Can someone check if this is correct,please?** I really appreciate any suggestions or correction.

Comment: I guess that $z:=x+iy$, right? Then the absolute value is just an absolute value of real values, because $x+y$ is real. Then $\partial_x|x+y|$ and $\partial_y|x+y|$ exists whenever $|x+y|\neq 0$, that is the same to say that when $x\neq -y$

Comment: There are two cases : or $f(z)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2y}-i(x+y)$ or $f(z)=\frac{y^2-x^2}{2y}+i(x+y)$. If one is complex differentiable the other is not.